# Upper Case in acronyms and plural

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am stuck with the glossary I wanted to use for acronyms. The Problem ist that now when I wanted to start a sentence it is written in lower case and also singular. I tried it with `makefirstuc` but did not succeed. Is there a way to force the first letter upper case and to write the word in plural?
Or can I write `Desoxyribonucleic Acid` int the Acronym list with Upper case and than in the text change the upper case `A` to a lower case `a`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

    \newacronym{dna}{DNA}{desoxyribonucleic acid}
    \newacronym{rna}{RNA}{ribonucleic acid}
    \newacronym{a}{A}{Adenosine}
    \newacronym{g}{G}{Guanine}
    \newacronym{c}{C}{Cytosine}
    \newacronym{t}{T}{Thymine}
    \newacronym{u}{U}{Uracil}

\begin{document}

    \section{DNA, RNA and Nucleobases}
    \gls{dna} contain the nucleobases  of \gls{a}, \gls{g}, \gls{c} and \gls{t}.
In contrast \gls{rna} contains \gls{u} instead of a \gls{t}.
\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probalby `\Glspl` gives you the desired output?

Comment: Hello Thank you very much, this solves the singular/plural problem.

Comment: Sorry missed the upper case G. It solved both problems. Thank you very much.